# Mysql server doesn't start on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and recently my database stopped working (don't know why, maybe after an update). When I tried to reinstall `mysql-server-5.7` it returned errors on install so I purged everything and switched to `mysql-server-5.6`, this version installs but it won't run. This is the output:

```
mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Čet 2017-02-02 10:00:15 CET; 8s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 9225 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 12545 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 02 09:59:44 alen-Aspire-E1-570G systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon...
Feb 02 09:59:44 alen-Aspire-E1-570G mysql[9225]:  * Starting MySQL database server mysqld
Feb 02 09:59:44 alen-Aspire-E1-570G su[9259]: Successful su for mysql by root
Feb 02 09:59:44 alen-Aspire-E1-570G su[9259]: + ??? root:mysql
Feb 02 09:59:44 alen-Aspire-E1-570G su[9259]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user mysql by (uid=0)
Feb 02 10:00:15 alen-Aspire-E1-570G mysql[9225]:    ...fail!
Feb 02 10:00:15 alen-Aspire-E1-570G systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 02 10:00:15 alen-Aspire-E1-570G systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
Feb 02 10:00:15 alen-Aspire-E1-570G systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 02 10:00:15 alen-Aspire-E1-570G systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I hope someone will be able to help me since I'm out of ideas.
EDIT: Mysql error log: http://pastebin.com/tuMj1AA7

Comment: Any relevant error in system log `/var/log/syslog` or mysql log?

Comment: @Khaled I updated my question with mysql error log. I see "mariadb" is mentioned in that log, I was trying to install mariadb several day before, but that failed too.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same problem and suspect it is related to apparmor.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=865534

TL;DR - Try this:

1. `echo -n "/usr/sbin/mysqld" | sudo tee /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/.remove`
2. `sudo service mysql start`

Comment: when your ubuntu-desktop docker can not start mysql container, this may help you, just do the first step!

Answer (score 2):

You should read the logs you post, they actually contain useful information that you could use to solve the problem yourself.

> 170202 09:48:16 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql 
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
>   Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted

Your startup failed because the permissions on `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/` are incorrect.

I don't have an Ubuntu system to hand to check but it should be fairly straightforward to figure out what permissions are required. you probably need to give read(r) and/or traverse(x) permissions to either group or world.

Answer (score 1):

There may be many reasons for the same error.

1. Try stop and start again mysqld with sudo command `sudo service mysqld stop` and then `sudo service mysqld start`.
2. check the memory if enough by using `df -h` command.
3. if this will not work then please paste mongo.cnf with your question.